# Chan Ho Park's Earned Runs Allowed on April 23, 1999

Tags: baseball, scoring

I saw a crazy stat today where Fernando Tatis Sr. hit two grand slams *in a single inning*, and crazily enough both off of Chan Ho Park, on April 23, 1999 in a game between the St. Louis Cardinals and the L.A. Dodgers, something that has never been done before or since.

Baseball-Reference.com records Park as pitching 2.2 innings that day and giving up 11 runs. However, only 6 of them were counted as earned.

```
Pitching                IP  H  R ER BB SO HR   ERA
Chan Ho Park L (1-2)   2.2  8 11  6  3  2  3  7.32
Carlos Perez           4.1  3  1  1  0  4  1  7.06
Jeff Kubenka             2  0  0  0  2  1  0 12.27
Team Totals              9 11 12  7  5  7  4  7.00
```

Provided by [Baseball-Reference.com](https://www.sports-reference.com/sharing.html?utm_source=direct&utm_medium=Share&utm_campaign=ShareTool): [View Original Table](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/LAN/LAN199904230.shtml?sr&utm_source=direct&utm_medium=Share&utm_campaign=ShareTool#LosAngelesDodgerspitching)

I don't know what the official rules on this were back in 1999, but I can't imagine they changed much.

> 9.16 Earned Runs and Runs Allowed
>
> An earned run is a run for which a pitcher is held accountable. In
> determining earned runs, the Official Scorer shall reconstruct the
> inning without the errors (which exclude catcher’s interference) and
> passed balls, giving the benefit of the doubt always to the pitcher in
> determining which bases would have been reached by runners had there
> been errorless play.

I get that [it depends](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/22767/26278) [on the situation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/29222/26278), but to me, given that at least 8 of the runs (in just this one inning) came off Tatis' two grand slams and not as a result of any error (i.e. these were legitimate hits), how is it that Park isn't charged at least 8 earned runs as well?

Comment: "not as a result of any error" Why do you say this? The play-by-play clearly shows an error by in the 3rd inning.

Comment: "not as a result of any error" meaning the plays that scored them were bona fide home runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no error on the home run plays, but there was an error in between.  Once you get to a point in the inning where you would have had 3 outs with errorless play, all further runs are considered unearned.

When McGuire flied out for the second out, plus Karros's error, there "should have" been 3 outs.   There were 7 runs at that point, 6 earned and 1 unearned.

All runs later in the inning (in this case, all the runs from Tatis's grand slam) are also unearned.

[MLB Rules](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/wqn5ah4c3qtivwx3jatm.pdf) 9.16

> In
> determining earned runs, the Official Scorer shall reconstruct the
> inning without the errors (which exclude catcher’s interference) and
> passed balls, giving the benefit of the doubt always to the pitcher in
> determining which bases would have been reached by runners had
> there been errorless play.

...

9.16(a) Comment 3 confirms that home runs may be unearned due to earlier errors in the inning.

> With two out, Abel reaches first on an error by the
> shortstop in misplaying a ground ball. Baker hits a
> home run. Charlie strikes out. Two runs have scored,
> but none is earned, because Abel’s at-bat should have
> been the third out of the inning, as reconstructed without
> the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is where play-by-play gives us context. Let's take a look at [Baseball Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/LAN/LAN199904230.shtml#all_play_by_play).

For the first home run, these are all earned runs.

| Inn | Score | Out | RoB | Pit(cnt) | R/O | @Bat | Batter | Pitcher | wWPA | wWE | Play Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t3 | 0-2 | 0 | --- | 2,(1-0) |  | STL | Darren Bragg | Chan Ho Park | 4% | 33% | Single to RF (Ground Ball thru 2B-1B) |
| t3 | 0-2 | 0 | 1-- | 5,(2-2) |  | STL | Edgar Renteria | Chan Ho Park | 6% | 39% | Hit By Pitch; Bragg to 2B |
| t3 | 0-2 | 0 | 12- | 2,(0-1) |  | STL | Mark McGwire | Chan Ho Park | 9% | 48% | Single to RF (Line Drive to Deep 2B-1B); Bragg to 3B; Renteria to 2B |
| t3 | 0-2 | 0 | 123 | 3,(2-0) | RRRR | STL | Fernando Tatís | Chan Ho Park | 23% | 71% | Home Run (Fly Ball to Deep LF); Bragg Scores; Renteria Scores; McGwire Scores |

For the second home run, there is an error. This dispels the claim that "at least 8 of the runs (in just this one inning) came off Tatis' two grand slams and ***not as a result of any error***" and further elaborated in [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/29409/26263).

| Inn | Score | Out | RoB | Pit(cnt) | R/O | @Bat | Batter | Pitcher | wWPA | wWE | Play Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t3 | 5-2 | 1 | 123 | 3,(1-1) | R | STL | Darren Bragg | Chan Ho Park | 5% | 90% | Reached on E3 (throw) (Ground Ball to Weak 2B-1B); Polanco Scores/No RBI; McEwing to 3B; Jimenez to 2B |
| t3 | 6-2 | 1 | 123 | 5,(2-2) | R | STL | Edgar Renteria | Chan Ho Park | 4% | 93% | Single to RF (Line Drive to Short RF Line); McEwing Scores/unER; Jimenez to 3B; Bragg to 2B |
| t3 | 7-2 | 1 | 123 | 4,(1-2) | O | STL | Mark McGwire | Chan Ho Park | -2% | 91% | Flyball: RF |
| t3 | 7-2 | 2 | 123 | 6,(3-2) | RRRR | STL | Fernando Tatís | Chan Ho Park | 7% | 98% | Home Run (Fly Ball); Jimenez Scores/unER; Bragg Scores/unER; Renteria Scores/unER; Tatis Scores/unER |

Comment: Isn't it simply that Renteria and Tatis are unearned because the inning would have been over with McGwire's out if it weren't for the error?

Comment: That could be - I'm addressing the claim that the runs were not a result of an error.